# Profiling MVC, which methods to profile to determine start and end of request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've written a basic profiler using the CLR Profiler API.  It's pretty simple, when a method is Jitted a logging class is inserted into the IL.  Works fine.

But I now want to identify when an MVC request starts and ends.  I would also like access to the HttpContext so I can obtain information about the request.

Which methods should I profile to correctly determine the start and end of an MVC request?

Please note. I want to achieve this aim by continuing to inject profiling code using the CLR Profiler API.

Comment: This is what is hit first in MVC. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutingmodule(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DerekHackett thanks will take a look.  I think this method is jitted already when .net is installed but I should be able to force it to be re-jitted.  Would be better if I didn't have to do this though.

Answer (score 0):

There's literally `BeginRequest` and `EndRequest` events in the ASP.NET lifecycle. Just add the appropriate handlers in `Global.asax`, i.e. define the `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` methods.

Comment: Thanks, I could also subscribe to the events in a HttpModule but I'm using the CLR Profiler API to inject profiling code.  I would like to continue with this approach and not require the user to change their code or install a HttpModule.